# Insert a row in a table without committing a required foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I have two tables with one having a foreign key constraint over the primary key of another table.
I need to perform a transaction where i need to insert an entry into both the tables and commit the transaction only if both entries are successful, otherwise rollback the complete transaction,

but since there is a foreign key constraint in the second table, and the entry in the first table is not yet committed, insertion onto the second table cannot be executed.

The Table Structures are as follows:

orderMaster

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| OID      | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CUSTOMER | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| DATE     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

orderDetails

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| OID   | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ITEM  | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| QUANT | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here the OID field in the orderDetails table is a foreign key from the orderMaster table.

I am saving the entries into the table using hibernate as

```
try{
        transaction.begin();
        session.save(orderMaster);
        boolean status=false;
        OrderDetailsDAO odao= new OrderDetailsDAO();
        System.out.println(orderDetails.size());
        for(OrderDetails od: orderDetails){
            status=odao.saveOrder(od);
            if(!status)
                break;
        }
        if(!status){
            txn.rollback();
            return false;
        }
        else{
        txn.commit();
        return true;
        }
    }catch(HibernateException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if(txn!=null)
            txn.rollback();
        return false;
    }
```

My Stack Trace is as follows:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cart`.`orderdetails`, CONSTRAINT `FKB8CC1F34C5FC9376` FOREIGN KEY (`OID`) REFERENCES `ordermaster` (`OID`))
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1669)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1085)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 37 more
```

How do i insert into the both the tables?

If the complete entry is done on both the tables, only then should the transaction be committed, otherwise a rollback should occur.

Comment: because of that foreign key constraint you cannot do what you are asking. You will have to commit to the first table so that you have a foreign key to use in the second table.

Comment: The inserts to both tables would have to be done within the same transaction.  Auto commit might need to be set to off, and commit after both inserts.

Comment: Ms sql or mysql? These are 2 different products, pls remove the irrelevant tag!

Comment: @rabbitguy changes done in a transaction are visible to the subsequent queries within that transaction, sometimes even outside of the transaction, if the isolation level is set to read uncommited.

Comment: @Shadow how to set the isolation level of the transaction to read uncommitted.

Comment: @user3879941 **do not** set the isolation level to read uncommited, this was not the point of my previous comment!

Answer (score 0):

This would not be a problem unless you have introduced a circular dependency.  Make sure you satisfy the foreign key dependency BEFORE you insert the row that runs afoul thereof.  You can insert the row with a NULL value in the errant column and then, after taking care of the foreign referencer, updating the NULL value to a significant FK-referential value.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have not set `orderDetails.OID`.

1. `session.save(orderMaster)`
2. Get the value of `orderMaster.OID`
3. Set `orderDetails.OID` to that value

Comment: The orderDetails.OID is already set, the problem is with the transaction. Both the save methods use different transactions and since the first transaction is not committed, the other cannot read it

Comment: Please point to the line of code in which orderDetails.OID is set.